# Android Custom View Size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am attempting to create my own view in android which is simply an oval and will be drawn correctly based on the typical **android:layout_width** and **android:layout_height** parameters.

So for example, if in my XML layout file, I have a LinearLayout which is the highest level View Container, I then want to be able to add multiple of my own oval Views. (which I called "PieFiller")

I know I am very close, but for some reason, I do not know how to determine if the user in the XML file said "fill_parent" or "wrap_content" and I don't know if I should even be asking for that information. Lets assume that wrap_content would simply draw a circle that is 40x40 pixels. But, if the XML layout file specifies that the width should "fill_parent" and the height "wrap_content" I want a long horizontal oval that is 40 pixels high and the number of pixels of the screen across.

Below is the code from my layout xml file and my custom view:

**layout file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.relativelayoutexample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.relativelayoutexample.PieFiller
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:labelPosition="left"
        custom:showText="true" />

    <com.example.relativelayoutexample.PieFiller
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:labelPosition="left"
        custom:showText="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom view class called "PieFiller"**

```
package com.example.relativelayoutexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class PieFiller extends View
{
    private boolean mShowText;
    private int mTextPos;

    private Paint paint;

    private RectF mBounds;

    public PieFiller(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);


        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PieFiller,0,0);

        try
        {
            mShowText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PieFiller_showText, false);
            mTextPos = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PieFiller_labelPosition, 0);
        }
        finally
        {
            a.recycle();
        }


        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBounds = new RectF();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(40.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int minw = getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
        int w = Math.max(minw,MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));

        int minh = this.getSuggestedMinimumHeight();
        int h = Math.max(minh, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));

        setMeasuredDimension(w,h);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        mBounds = new RectF(0,0,w,h);
    }

    public boolean ismShowText()
    {
        return mShowText;
    }
    public void setmShowText(boolean mShowText)
    {
        this.mShowText = mShowText;
        this.invalidate();
        this.requestLayout();
    }
    public int getmTextPos()
    {
        return mTextPos;
    }
    public void setmTextPos(int mTextPos)
    {
        this.mTextPos = mTextPos;
        this.invalidate();
        this.requestLayout();
    }



}
```

By the way, the result of the code posted above, the first PieFiller takes up the entire screen. (which I don't want it to)

Comment: I am sorry, I don't me the actual oval gets drawn the entire screen, but the other PieFiller doesn't even appear and when I look at the Graphical tool and click on the first PieFiller the blue box around the oval takes up the entire screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside onMeasure() of your custom view add below logic:

```
int width = 100;
    if(getLayoutParams().width==LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    {
        width = 40;
    }
    else if((getLayoutParams().width==LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)||(getLayoutParams().width==LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT))
    {
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    }
    else
        width = getLayoutParams().width;


    int height = 100;
    if(getLayoutParams().height==LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    {

    }
    else if((getLayoutParams().height==LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)||(getLayoutParams().height==LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT))
    {
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    }
    else
        height = getLayoutParams().height;


    setMeasuredDimension(width|MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, height|MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
```